Avalonia error AVLN:0004: Unable to resolve property or method of name 'Test' on type 'Avalonia_Blog.Models.Post'
I'm trying to build a small blog post application. In it I iterate through a bunch of posts and in the view I pass a post to usercontrol called postrow
Posts.axaml
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Avalonia_Blog.Controls;assembly=Avalonia_Blog"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Avalonia_Blog.ViewModels"
             x:Class="Avalonia_Blog.Views.PostsView"
             x:DataType="vm:PostsViewModel">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Currently on:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UrlPathSegment} view" />
        <Button Content="Go to login"
                Command="{Binding GoToLogin}" />
                <Button Content="Post with ID 1"
                            Command="{Binding GoToPost}"
                            CommandParameter="1"/>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- <Button Content="{Binding Title}"
                            Command="{Binding $parent[vm:PostsViewModel].GoToPost}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding PostId}">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button> -->
                    <controls:PostRow Post="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>


In my postrow.axaml
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Avalonia_Blog.Models;assembly=Avalonia_Blog"
             x:Class="Avalonia_Blog.Controls.PostRow"
             x:DataType="local:Post">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="{Binding Title}" Command="{Binding Test }" />
    
        <!-- <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PostId}" /> -->
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>

I have a button that binds to a test function that's not included in my Post Model <Button Content="{Binding Title}" Command="{Binding Test }" />
When I run dotnet run
I get this error:

/Users/kylehurst/projects/Avalonia_Blog/Controls/PostRow.axaml(7,43,7,43): Avalonia error AVLN:0004: Unable to resolve property or method of name 'Test' on type 'Avalonia_Blog.Models.Post'. Line 7, position 43. [/Users/kylehurst/projects/Avalonia_Blog/Avalonia_Blog.csproj]

How do I access the test command from the PostRow usercontrol?
Here's a gist of code:
https://gist.github.com/corbin1988/13e58782cf858ffa0b81987ff1e8e175

It is unclear how your PostRowViewModel is supposed to be instantiated. The Posts property of the parent view model should certainly be ObservableCollection<PostRowViewModel> instead of ObservableCollection<Post>. It is also unclear why the PostRow control has a Post property. It should instead simply operate on the automatically inherited DataContext, which would then contain a PostRowViewModel instance. And it should have x:DataType="vm:PostRowViewModel".

In the PostRow.axaml you declare that binding will come from the Post model, but the Post model is not containing the Test command !! ... the Test command is existed in PostRowViewModel so let's fix that by change the type
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Avalonia_Blog.ViewModels"
             x:Class="Avalonia_Blog.Controls.PostRow"
             x:DataType="vm:PostRowViewModel">
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="{Binding Title}" Command="{Binding Test }" /> 
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>

and in your PostsViewModel class when you get the Posts from the service map it to PostRowViewModel object as following
public class PostsViewModel : ViewModelBase, IRoutableViewModel
{
    private readonly PostService _postService;
    public ObservableCollection<PostRowViewModel> Posts { get; } // <<<<< use ObservableCollection<PostRowViewModel> instade of  ObservableCollection<Post>
    //...
    public PostsViewModel(IScreen screen)
    {  
        //..
        _postService = new PostService();
        // map every post to PostRowViewModel as following
        Posts = new(_postService.GetPosts().Select(p => new PostRowViewModel { PostId = p.Id, Title = p.Title }));

        //..
    }
}

after this modification it should work just fine
